# Websocket closes automatically when server has no ping interval

Tags: python, typescript, browser, websocket, client-server

I have seen a lot of questions regarding this issue , but all of them mention the idea of having to ping the server to keep the connection alive due to the server's protocol. The server in the below example has no requirement of ping/pong.The browser closes the connection automatically,  when trying to `send()` in the method `Bare.send_stuff` I get the following error:

`InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable`

Client(Typescript via React):

```
export class Bare{

    connections : Map<string,WebSocket>
    constructor(){
        this.connections = new Map<string,WebSocket>();
    }

    setup_connection(name:string){
        let connection = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:50223');
        this.connections.set(name,connection);

    }
    send_stuff(name:string){
        let connection = this.connections.get(name);
        connection.send("stuff");
    }
}
```

Server(Python):

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('websockets')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())

class Main:

    def __init__(self):
        self.host = '127.0.0.1' 
        self.port = 50223

    async def check_declaration(self,websocket,path):
        while True:
            data = await websocket.recv()
            print(data)
            
    def start_server(self):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.run_until_complete(
            websockets.serve(self.check_declaration,self.host,self.port,ping_interval=None))
        loop.run_forever()

Main().start_server()
```

Is there anyway to keep the connection alive on the client end without the need of pings?

**Edit** the below client works completely fine with the server:

```
const connection = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:50223');
const sayHi = () => connection.send('hi');
connection.onopen = () => {
  setInterval(sayHi, 5*60*1000);
  sayHi();
};
connection.onmessage = ({data}) => console.log(data);
```

This leads me to believe the browsers don't keep connections open unless the connection is referenced in the event loop? Not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the browser closes all WebSocket connections if they aren't referenced or the callback functions for the connection aren't declared. Instead of initializing the connection with `setup_connection` and then waiting to send data with `send_stuff` , I began a different task altogether that runs on an interval so the browser client doesn't close the connection prematurely.

New client:

```
const connection = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:50223');
const sayHi = () => connection.send('hi');
connection.onopen = () => {
  setInterval(sayHi, 5*60*1000);
  sayHi();
};
```

In my findings investigating this problem loosely, the browser doesn't allow you to establish a connection without referencing that connection, you would need to declare a callback immediately after initialization of the connection. Declaring the `.send` function on an interval or declaring the `.onmessage` callback function should keep the connection alive.